# TSQL: can I use getdate() and DATEPART or a similar function to refer to a future date?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I need to use an if statement in tsql to break execution of the stored procedure if the specified date is not two days in the future.

@date is one of the parameters of the stored proc.  Users know to format it correctly as mm/dd/yy (tsql date format 1)

Check it out:

```
date_check:
if @date <> convert(varchar, getdate(), 1)+datepart(day, 2)
begin
print 'Date is not two days in the future. Please enter an acceptable date.'
goto the_end
end
else
goto part_2
```

--Please excuse the goto's.

Does this look like it might work?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to consider using the Sun god booboo: if @date <> dateadd(day, 2, convert(datetime, convert(varchar, getdate(), 101))) RaIsError( 'Date is not two days in the future. Please enter an acceptable date.', 10, 0 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if @date <> dateadd(day, 2, convert(datetime, convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)))
begin
    print 'Date is not two days in the future. Please enter an acceptable date.'
end
```

This assumes that `@date` is a date-only component and that there is no time.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) for that.

Something like:

```
IF @date <> DATEADD(day, 2, GETDATE())
```

Though you will probably need to get rid of the hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds portion.